# How to show an icon when text is selected using Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a Chrome Extension. The only challenge here is to show an icon when some text is selected on any page and when they click on that icon it should open our extension with selected text. We are building the extension using Angular 9.

> One of the extension already has this feature - Natural Reader Text to
> Speech

**Sample image from the extension**
[image]

I searched in google but couldnot find a valid solution :(

Comment: This is a standard DOM thing, not specific to extensions. Listen to `contextmenu` event and add an element, position it relatively to selection by using the standard DOM methods like getBoundingClientRect and CSS positioning. You can do it in a *content script*.

Comment: Ok thanks will try it @wOxxOm